# SQL inner join issue with getting exact value by id

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I have such query:

```
SELECT `type` FROM `data_user` table1 INNER JOIN
`user_type` table2 ON table1.username = 'sber'
```

I'm getting all rows from `user_type`, but I need only the type value in table `user_type` where id equals to the id from `data_user`.

How to fix this query for what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT `type` 
FROM `data_user` table1 
INNER JOIN `user_type` table2 ON (table1.username = 'sber' AND 
    table1.id = table2.id)
```

Comment: Random question, does it make any difference if table1.username = 'sber' is in the Join, or if it were to be moved to the WHERE Clause? It's effectively the same thing right?

Comment: Having it where clause is better readability and better performance. Those who doubt performance - try it yourself :-)

Comment: @hop - you're right.. it is easier to read.  I think performance in this simple case would be negligible, but in large queries with multiple joins it could make a difference.